# Dynamically javascript loading. Event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with dynamically loading javascript files.

I'll try explain my problem on example. So for example I'm loading first_file.js. In this file I have some event handlers/listener. After that I'll return to my main page(via Ajax, so no page reload). **AND** after that I'm loading first_file.js again. And all events handlers will be added second time. So when event fire, all handlers executed two times.

The main problem is: first_file.js handlers can be added in several ways. Like a jQuery.on, or simple addEventListener.

And also first_file.js should be added 2 times anyway, because it contain not only event registration.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Use delegated event handlers that are only loaded once? You've shot yourself in the foot by mixing `addEventListener()` and `on()` really. Consistency is key.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'm trying to make something like an ajaxify script, which will translate any site, to ajax version. So I don't know how events implemented.

Comment: Sorry to say that without iframes (and iframes make me retch) I don't believe that "any site" can be automatically translated to an ajax version. Not without some sort of artificial-intelligence level of understanding...Issues like this are part of the reason why; and why newbies are warned to make their code more extensible. (ie, "Stop naming your list elements with id="1", id="2", etc")

Comment: You could override the event registering functions before loading the javascript file the second time. Libraries ultimately rely on native support. Another way you could attain you goal is to preprocess the file to remove the handlers before loadign it.

Comment: >You could override the event registering


I now do so. And I override jquery.on and addEventListener. But what if other framework/library using another way? I should add this `another` way in my code. It's quite good, but I thought maybe somebody knows a better way.